# Sublime seems to be locking files

Tags: symfony, sublimetext2

I am using Sublime Text 2 and Symfony2.

I'm not sure what changed, but Sublime Text 2 seems to be locking files as read only all of a sudden. I'm using the `assets:install` command for Symfony2, and I keep getting the error `Failed to remove directory ...`. When I close out Sublime Text 2, Symfony is able to delete the files.

It works about 50% of the time. Any ideas?

Comment: But then why would closing sublime fix it?

Comment: Try closing all files in Sublime, then retry assets:install. Are you using the --symlink flag?

Comment: Can't use symlink as I'm on windows. Closing out of Sublime is only solution I've found so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to [Sublime Text 3 Beta](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) (free for Sublime Text 2 users during beta period) fixed this issue for me on Windows 8.

I experienced the file locking issue without any frameworks or automation. If a file or folder was open in Sublime Text 2 (or had been previously opened during the session), I couldn't manually delete it in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Great, will try that out. As an aside, this isn't really an issue for me anymore because I now use Assetic - if you haven't starting this yet, it could save you a lot of time and headaches!

Comment: Sounds good. Would you consider marking this as accepted if it solved your issue? I was actually having the issue without any frameworks - updated my answer above.

Comment: Windows 8.1 with all updates? I haven't experienced this issue any more since ST3. Maybe a reinstall would help? If not, does Process Explorer show any strange file handles? http://windowsxp.mvps.org/processlock.htm

Comment: Same in Windows 7 SP1 - locks files, specifically for RequireJS build over Node.

Comment: Sublimw Text 3 Build 3065 locks my files on Windows 8.1 with all upgrades. My IIS freezes sometimes and requires a reboot to recover (can't restart the pool or kill the process), I don't know if it's because of Sublime.

Comment: Same problem in Sublime text 2 Version 2.0.2 Build 2221 on Kubuntu Linux 15.10

Comment: Same problem with Sublime Text 3 Version 3.1.1 Build 3176 on Windows 10 (1803)